# HTMl Anchor tag in stored procedure

Tags: html, sql-server, stored-procedures

i want to use a anchor tag in stored procedure that would be sent as a body of the mail and it's not working

```
declare @loginlink VARCHAR(MAX)=N'';
```

SELECT @loginlink= N'['+ CONVERT(varchar(36),@loginlink)+'ClickMe](http://localhost/Project/CaseHistory/History?caseId=) ' AS CaseLink

Comment: I think you forgot the question. There are no details in this post at all. What is the question? What are you trying to do? What you have here so far will return "ClickMe". Please see this article. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to set a T-SQL variable to an HTML anchor, then you could use the code below. Just replace the href value with the value in your situation.

Note the use of two single quotes around href value. This is necessary since we want single quote to be around the href value and we are using single quotes for enclosing string in SQL Server.

```
declare @loginlink VARCHAR(MAX)=N'';
set @loginlink = '<a href=''http://www.yahoo.com''>Click Me</a>';
SELECT @loginlink as CaseLink;
```

If you want to use a T-SQL variable for the href part of anchor link, then you can use code like below.

```
declare @loginlink VARCHAR(MAX)=N'';
DECLARE @href  varchar(500);
SET @href = 'http://www.yahoo.com';

set @loginlink = '<a href=''' + @href + '''>Click Me</a>';
SELECT @loginlink as CaseLink;
```

If you are sending this link using `database mail` then you need to create a html page with all relevant html tags and send that as body, plus you need to make sure that the mail format is `Html`.

```
declare @body nvarchar(max)
set @body = '<html><head><title>Results</title></head><body>' + @loginlink + '</body></html>'

EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name='emailProfile',
  @copy_recipients ='abc@xyz.com',
  @recipients='opq@oxyz.com',
  @subject='New Results',
  @body=@body , --this needs to be an html with all necessary html tags
  @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

Comment: Not working it is treating it as a string which i don't want

Comment: How are you using it? It works on my end when I copy and paste into a html page.

Comment: If you are sending via `database mail` then you need to create the body as a html page with all html page tags and not just the anchor link by itself.

Comment: Not working it is treating hyperlink  as a string which i don't want. and also the output is like 
'<a href=''' + http://www.yahoo.com + '''>Click Me</a>'

Comment: How are you sending this link? Can you post code that sends this email? If you are using database email then look at new code that I have just added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

OMG it was a very silly mistake i did

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'dbo'  
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @recipients='abc.com   ',
      @copy_recipients='abc.com',
      --@blind_copy_recipients=
      @from_address = 'abc.com',
      --@reply_to=
      @importance='High', -- High | Normal | Low
      @profile_name = 'test',
      @subject = @EmailSubject, 
      @body = @EmailBody,
     @body_format='HTML'; --TEXT | HTML
```

> @body_format='HTML'; --TEXT | HTML ::: my body format of mail was set to text that is why it was not treating anchor tag as it

Comment: That is what I mentioned in my post today an hour aback.`plus you need to make sure that the mail format is Html.`